# Using the verbs "Leave" and "Move" when it comes to a vehicle

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference, verbs

Let's suppose it's 5 o'clock in the afternoon and you're in a train that will leave at 5:30.
Someone calls you and asks if the train has left the station or it's still there.
You reply:

> No, the train has not ....... yet.

**a. left** (the usual way to say that) 
**b. moved** (I need to know whether this verb works here too or bot.)

Then the same person calls you at 6 and wants to make sure if you have left the source or you're still there. You answer:

> Yes, the train ........... at 5:30 sharp.

**a. left** (the usual way to say that) 
**b. moved** (I need to know whether this verb works here too or bot.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At 5 o'clock we would say the train **has not left**, and at 6 o'clock we would say it **left** at 5.30 sharp. We would not use 'move' because it might mean that it moved within the station without leaving.

Answer (score 1):

It would be fine to say "The train hasn't moved yet". It is a bit of rhetorical emphasis. "The train hasn't left, it hasn't even moved an inch"

It would be odd to say "The train moved at 5:30".  It suggests that the train moved a small amount, but remained in the station.